# best way to create a dict of the given string in python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dict of values out of this string

```
'idle (images=green:200, inpadoc=green:60, other=green:1000, retrieval=green:200, search=green:30)'
```

output:

```
{'images':['green', 200], 'inpadoc':['green', 60],...}
```

what will be the best generic solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The string is wrong , strating bracket but no ending bracket

Comment: you are right, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
def main():
    x = 'idle (images=green:200, inpadoc=green:60, other=green:1000, retrieval=green:200, search=green:30)'
    x= x.replace("idle (", "")
    x= x.replace(")", "")
    tmp = x.split(',')

    tmp2 = dict( i.split('=') for i in tmp )

    for item in tmp2:        
        tmp2[item] = tmp2[item].split(":")

    print tmp2  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the `'ìdle ('` bit. Then split on `', '`, then split on `'='`, then split on `':'`.

Comment: You can try to give more detailed answer, such as how to convert the split string into dictionary.

Comment: @justhalf: You use the `split()` function of the string. This is all very simple, you need to try and ask specific questions about the problems you have. I'm not going to write the whole solution for you, that's not how you learn, and also I charge money for that. ;-)

Comment: But the OP is asking how to convert that into `dict`, that's why I think you answer was insufficient =)

Comment: @justhalf: If you know the syntax of how to create a dict, that answer is obvious. If you don't, you need to read a tutorial.

Comment: There still are various ways to convert it, as presented in my answers.

But I understand your concerns =D

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'idle (images=green:200, inpadoc=green:60, other=green:1000, retrieval=green:200, search=green:30'
str = str.split('(')[1]
dict = {}
for sublist in str.split(','):
    split1 = sublist.split('=')
    split2 = split1[1].split(':')
    dict[split1[0]] = [split2[0],int(split2[1])]

print dict
```

Ouput

```
{'images': ['green', 200], ' other': ['green', 1000], ' search': ['green', 30], ' retrieval': ['green', 200], ' inpadoc': ['green', 60]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
# Get rid of unwanted part of the string
text='idle (images=green:200, inpadoc=green:60, other=green:1000, retrieval=green:200, search=green:30)'
text = text[text.find(' ')+1:].strip('()')

# Define the converter function
def converter(string):
    [key,value] = string.split('=') # Split into ['images','green:200']
    value = value.split(':') # Split into ['images',['green','200']]
    value[1] = int(value[1]) # Convert the number into int ['images',['green':200]]
    return [key,value]

print dict(map(converter,text.split(', ')))
```

So first, you get rid of the 'idle' and the parentheses.

Then you define the function to convert each entry (`images=green:200`) into a two-element list (`['images',['green',200]]`), which will be converted into dictionary automatically using the `dict` function.

Using `map` function is faster than just iterating over the list, which is the beauty of Python.

EDIT:

Oops, apparently using this `map` function is not faster than simply iterating over the list.

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    dict(map(converter,text.split(', ')))
print 'Done in %.3fs' % (time.time()-startTime)
# Done in 1.703s

startTime = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    result = {}
    for element in text.split(', '):
        [key,value] = element.split('=')
        value = value.split(':')
        value[1] = int(value[1])
        result[key] = value
print 'Done in %.3fs' % (time.time()-startTime)
# Done in 1.405s
```

But you have your options to select. =D

Answer (score 0):

```
original = 'images=green:200,inpadoc=green:60,other=green:1000,retrieval=green:200,search=green:30'
parsed = {}
for e in original.split(','):
    split = e.split('=')
    parsed[split[0]] = split[1].split(':')
```

I hope this is readable enough for you. This solution is similar to the solution given by all these people before me, but it was a fun coffee break exercise nonetheless :)